# Please help my idea send data from this SWF to another SWF

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4

I have an idea. I want to send data from SWF on this machine to SWF on another machine in Internet. I know Cirrus of Adobe maybe help this.

I used Browser(Chrome) for run SWF and I uploaded file SWF to Internet.

I tried used LocalConnection but it only work on local machine

I also tried  NetConnection and NetStream but not success.

So who have any idea can help me. Thank you so much....

Sorry for my bad English!

Comment: What kind of data are you wanting to send back and forth?  The way you should probably send the data would depend on the situation, although you probably will end up using NetConnections and NetStreams.

Answer (score 0):

You may try UDP. But, the data is not sure to go because it is UDP.

NetConnection is used for client server. 
LocalConnection is for swf on the same machine.

A solution could be to use Blazeds, blaze takes the requests and pushes the messages to the second client, vice versa. But, direct connection between two AIR or Flash players using UDP is non reliant.

Look for UDP [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/DatagramSocket.html) 
Blazeds [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/blazeds/1/blazeds_devguide/) and [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/livecycle/articles/blazeds_gettingstarted.html)

in btwn, what is Cirrus of Adobe?

Answer (score 0):

Other than using BlazeDS (or GraniteDS which I actually like a little better) messaging services, there's the option of using AIR + Flex.  Unfortunately it's never going to be quite this easy from a browser (Flash).

This looks like a decent enough example:

http://mariusht.com/blog/2010/02/13/sending-messages-from-server-socket-to-client-sockets/